# Explanation of numerical integration method in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following MATLAB code that computes the integration of a function numerically.  I don't know what `xi0` and `xi1` mean:

```
function [xin,cota] = trapecios2(f,a,b,n,M)
%Cálculo aproximado de la integral de f en [a,b]
%utilizando el método de los trapecios
% f es la función a y b los extremos del intervalo n es el número de
% subintervalos en los que se divide [a,b]
if n<=0 
    disp('valor de n no válido')
    return
end
h=(b-a)/n;
xi0=f(a)+f(b);
xi1=0;
for i=1:n-1
    x=a+i*h;
    xi1=xi1+f(x);
end
xin=h*(xi0+2*xi1)/2;
cota=(M/12)*(b-a)^3/n^2
end
```

Comment: You could ask the one from whom you got this code what the variables mean. He should know but maybe noone else may know too. This is probably not a real programming question then.

Comment: Writing the comments in the function in english might help people better understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This function is computing the integral numerically as you have stated.  However, what's important to note is that this function is approximating the area underneath the curve using **trapezoids**.  You probably don't know about the [trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), because if you did, then you can see that this code approximates the integral using the trapezoidal rule.  Also, in your comments block at the top of your code, it does say that the area is being calculated by trapezoids, albeit in Spanish. The premise behind the trapezoidal rule is that we fit `N` trapezoids underneath the curve, calculate the area of each trapezoid and sum up all of the areas.  This is an approximation to the area that is underneath the curve.

Specifically, if we wanted to compute the area under the curve between the beginning at `x = a` up to `x = b`, and we have `N` trapezoids, then trapezoidal rule is such that:

[image]

Also:

[image]

Therefore, in your code, `xi0` computes `f(a) + f(b)`, which are the first and last term inside the large brackets of the first equation.  Next, `xi1` computes the summation, which is the middle term inside the large brackets of first equation.  This is done in the `for` loop in your code.  Finally, we compute the total area by this statement in your code:

```
xin=h*(xi0+2*xi1)/2;
```

If you substitute `xi0` and `xi1` into the above statement, this essentially computes the trapezoidal rule to compute the area underneath the curve.

---

FWIW, `cota` at the end of the code computes the maximum error of the area approximated by the trapezoidal rule in comparison the true area.  Specifically:

[image]

`M` specifies an upper limit of what the error should be.  This is the last input into your function.

---

Hope this helps!